# WooCommerce / WC Vendors: Display product name and meta after title in product edit forms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wcvendors

I'm using WC Vendors Pro which lets you add/edit WooCommerce products from the frontend. Now I want to display the product name and a meta field (SKU) after the title of the product edit form.

I added a custom function which displays the dummy data in a correct way:

```
add_action( 'wcvendors_before_product_form', 'vendor_dashboard_product_title_after_headline_product_form', 0 );
function vendor_dashboard_product_title_after_headline_product_form(){

    echo '<h3>Name</h3>';
    echo '<p>SKU</p>';

}
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to get the ID of the product which I'm editing.

I tried to use the following:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );  
$product->get_name();
```

But it shows an error. I guess `$product` doesn't work because there is no `$product_id` in the form (the form is a normal page).

So I looked into the template file and it shows the following code at the beginning:

```
$title      = ( is_numeric( $object_id ) ) ? __( 'Save Changes', 'wcvendors-pro' ) : __( 'Add Product', 'wcvendors-pro' );
$page_title = ( is_numeric( $object_id ) ) ? __( 'Edit Product', 'wcvendors-pro' ) : __( 'Add Product', 'wcvendors-pro' );
$product    = ( is_numeric( $object_id ) ) ? wc_get_product( $object_id ) : null;
$post       = ( is_numeric( $object_id ) ) ? get_post( $object_id ) : null;

// Get basic information for the product
$product_title             = ( isset( $product ) && null !== $product ) ? $product->get_title() : '';
$product_description       = ( isset( $product ) && null !== $product ) ? $post->post_content : '';
$product_short_description = ( isset( $product ) && null !== $product ) ? $post->post_excerpt : '';
$post_status               = ( isset( $product ) && null !== $product ) ? $post->post_status : '';
```

I tried to use the `$object_id`. But it is empty.
Even if I add it to my function like this:

```
function vendor_dashboard_product_title_after_headline_product_form($object_id){
```

Maybe that's the wrong way?!

Does anybody know how I get the product ID from the product I'm editing?
If I have the ID, I could get the rest to work.

**EDIT:**

If I use another hook, I can use `$object_id`. This works:

```
add_action( 'wcv_before_general_tab', 'vendor_dashboard_product_title_after_headline_product_form', 0 );
function vendor_dashboard_product_title_after_headline_product_form($object_id){
```

My problem is, that I don't want to use the hook `wcv_before_general_tab` because it's the wrong place.

Comment: What about using global `$product;` `if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->exists() ) {
 return;
}` And then `$product->get_id();` ?

Comment: that doesn't work because I'm not on a product page. The edit form is a simple page.

Comment: unfortunately that's the same problem. I get the ID of the page instead the ID of the product. I've edited my question because I found a way to use `$object_id`. But at the wrong place :(

Comment: Well I don't use that plugin, but a hook that seems to be used just before the title `do_action( 'wcv_before_product_details', $object_id );` https://docs.wcvendors.com/knowledge-base/adding-a-custom-field-for-products/ 
Maybe you can do something with that?

Comment: yes, that's working but it also is the "wrong place" ;). But a better place than `wcv_before_general_tab `